# Using sum and case as a loop in Oracle functions correctly

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I'm looping through a table to calculate **IncomeTax** taking **taxable** as a parameter. So the loop goes through the table,calculate and sum the values. I am stuck at where the **taxable** is less than **cummuativeamount** in the sum statement,then we multiply the **taxable * percentage**.The example explains the function I need.For example

```
taxable=2000,
do 2000-261=1739 and do 0% * 261 = 0,
go to next line do 1739-70=1669 and do 5% * 70=3.5,
go to next line do 1669-100=1569 and do 10% *100.
go to next line,do 1569 < 2810, it should be 1569 *17.5%
```

[image: multiply percentage by cummulative amount]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function CalculateIncomeTax2(taxableIncome NUMBER)
return NUMBER 
AS
IncomeTax NUMBER (10,2); 
BEGIN
SELECT 
 coalesce(SUM(     
  CASE WHEN (taxableIncome > T.TAX_CUMMULATIVE_AMOUNT) THEN ( 
(T.TAX_CUMMULATIVE_AMOUNT* T.TAX_PERCENTAGE)/ 100)                         
 ELSE 0.00 END
    ) ,0)                 
INTO IncomeTax
  FROM TAX_LAW T  

return IncomeTax
end; /
```

Comment: 4000 minus 261 is not 1739. Did you mean to start with taxable=2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're writing a PL/SQL function, but trying to do all the logic with a plain SQL query. I think this is certainly possible to do with a SQL query, but since your original logic is structured as a loop, you might have an easier time using a PL/SQL loop structure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function CalculateIncomeTax2(taxableIncome NUMBER)
return NUMBER 
AS
    IncomeTax NUMBER (10,2) := 0;
    TaxableRemainder NUMBER := taxableIncome;
BEGIN
    for r in (select tax_id, tax_percentage, tax_cummulative_amount
              from incometax
              order by tax_id)
    loop
        if TaxableRemainder > r.tax_cummulative_amount then
            TaxableRemainder := TaxableRemainder - r.tax_cummulative_amount;
            incometax := incometax + (r.tax_cummulative_amount * r.tax_percentage / 100);
        else
            incometax := incometax + (TaxableRemainder * r.tax_percentage / 100);
            exit; 
        end if;
    end loop;

    return IncomeTax;
end; 
/
```

For your example, I get `CalculateIncomeTax2(2000) = 288.08`. This is slightly different than what you'd normally get with a calculator (288.075) because you defined IncomeTax as NUMBER(10,2) with a precision of 2. But maybe that's what you want?

Edit: So in your SQL query, the main thing you're missing is that in order to keep a *running total* of the tax value for each row, you need an [analytic / window function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174). Here's an example of how you could do the same calculation in a plain SQL query. (You can simplify this query a lot, but I think it's more readable this way - you can easily look at a subquery to see how the data is built up.)

```
select sum(tax_component)
from (
    select tax_id, tax_percentage, tax_cummulative_amount,
        taxableRemainder,
        case when taxableRemainder > tax_cummulative_amount 
            then (tax_cummulative_amount * tax_percentage / 100)
            else (taxableRemainder * tax_percentage / 100)
            end as tax_component
    from (
        select tax_id, tax_percentage, tax_cummulative_amount,
            nvl(2000-sum(tax_cummulative_amount) 
                     over (order by tax_id 
                        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
                2000) 
                as taxableRemainder
        from incometax) it
)
;
```

Comment: The query I wrote works perfectly in sql to calculate the IncomeTax but not Plsql,I will try your logic although I don't really understand it 100%.thank you,I will get back to you.Is there any way I can contact you privately?

Comment: what is the difference between what I wrote in sql and what you did?